# My subquery returned more than 1 value In CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I tried to fetch some data from my stored procedure. `@ContactID` is the input parameter, where user clicks show button the query fires. So if `@ContactID` is null, then I want to return the whole table and when `@ContactID` has some value, then I want to return only that specific row. Thank you

```
DECLARE @ContactID INT = NULL

SELECT * 
FROM Contact C 
WHERE C.PK_Contact IN (CASE WHEN @ContactID IS NULL THEN (SELECT PK_Contact FROM Contact) ELSE @ContactID END)
```

But I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: `select PK_Contact from Contact` returns all the `PK_Contact`s from `Contact` table.

Comment: What is the datatype of `@ContactID` parameter and what it contains? Are you using SQL Server 2008 or 20012? BTW SQL Server 2008 is out of support you should really upgrade

Comment: yes so i want that WHERE C.PK_Contact IN (returned all PK's from Contact table)

Comment: @Sami Sorry for the tag sql-2008 and 12. i just joined stack overflow so i dont't know how to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just try this instead?

```
-- you should *really* get in the habit of explicitly spelling out which columns you need! 
-- Don't use "SELECT *" in production code!
SELECT *    
FROM dbo.Contact C 
WHERE C.PK_Contact = ISNULL(@ContactID, C.PK_Contact)
```

If `@ContactID` has a specific value - then you're just returning those rows that match that `ID` value. If `@ContactID` is NULL, then you're returning all rows.

Comment: @Hrv You should mark the best answer solve your issue as accepted. Please choose one of the two answers.

Comment: @Sami yes sure. but this will give popup that i can accept answer after 3 minutes!

Comment: @Hrv . . . This is the better solution.  It uses only basic boolean operations, rather than introduce `case` expressions in the `where` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and where is the problem with the case expression which is a standard? How is this better? *It uses only basic boolean operations* does a case statement use something different less efficient?

Comment: @forpas . . . `case` expressions impose an ordering on evaluation.  It is the only expression that really has such an ordering constraint.  That pretty much kills the optimizer.

Comment: @Hrv take some time and read why should avoid using functions like ISNULL() in the WHERE clause: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/ and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/ and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3204/avoid-using-functions-in-where-clause/

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see that my previous comment is deleted and I don't know why! Since when technical comments are deleted? So again: do you think that the optimizer is happier with a function than with a CASE statement? If so do you have proof about it? I posted links in my previous comment as a proof about why functions should be avoided. Do you have any to support what you said?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as well.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Contact
WHERE (@ContactID is null or PK_Contact = @ContactID)
```

---

**Example**
Table Structure & Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT, val INT);

INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES (1,'25'),
       (2,'55'),
       (3,'25'),
       (4,'10'),
       (5,'60');
```

---

When the input is null...

```sql
DECLARE @input INT = NULL

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (@input IS NULL OR id = @input)
```

*Output*

```
+-----+-----+
| id  | val |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  25 |
|  2  |  55 |
|  3  |  25 |
|  4  |  10 |
|  5  |  60 |
+-----+-----+
```

---

When the input is not null...

```sql
DECLARE @input INT = 2

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (@input IS NULL OR id = @input)
```

*Output*

```
+-----+-----+
| id  | val |
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  55 |
+-----+-----+
```

Online Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3780464672e02557458d22317aed40c9

Answer (score 0):

Remove IN and the subquery:

```
declare @ContactID int =null
SELECT * 
FROM Contact C 
WHERE C.PK_Contact = (CASE WHEN @ContactID IS NULL THEN C.PK_Contact ELSE @ContactID END)
```

So when `@ContactID is NULL` the condition is

```
WHERE C.PK_Contact = C.PK_Contact
```

which is always TRUE and this will return all rows.